# grub won't show custom menu entry

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 under a virtual machine.
I have to modify grub menu adding some custom entries. I try to edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and then run `update-grub`; however, no new menu entries are shown.

This is the content of my `40_custom` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "System restart" {
    echo "System rebooting..."
    reboot
}
menuentry "System shutdown" {
    echo "System shutting down..."
    halt
}
menuentry "Other Linux" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    linux /boot/vmlinuz 
    initrd /boot/initrd.img 
}
```

And this is what I get as a result:
[no new entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu2fN.png)

I took the menu entries from [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB) page (about Arch, but I don't think there should be difference in term of entry actually appearing in the menu).

I also can't use anything like any third-party software or whatnot, I have to edit the `40_custom` file manually or with something the standard Ubuntu package provides.

**Edit:**
Here is `ls -l /etc/grub.d | grep 40_custom` output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  626 May  1 09:44 40_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  466 May  1 09:39 40_custom~
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @mook765 Yes, I did.

Comment: Does it help if you use single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: @mook765 Unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: Please check the file-permissions of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` with `ls -l /etc/grub.d | grep 40_custom` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @mook765 edited the question.

Comment: @mook765 was it because the file was not executable? I ran 'sudo chmod 777 /etc/grub.d/40_custom', the menu entries appeared.

Comment: The correct premissions for this file are `755`, with `777` the file is world-writable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need execute permissions on the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

The command

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

will add the execute permissions to the file.

After doing that, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: i tried this, but didn't help

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment so I'll post as answer.
First mount boot partition(for me it's sda1), ad. /boot read below

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot
```

Then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Otherwise it will create grub.cfg on you're file system.
You can check what partitions you have mounted with

```
lsblk
```

Ad /boot:
You can check first when the file is created. Mine was in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, I checked that by default, relative to boot partition the file is in `/grub/grub.cfg`, So that's why I mounted it to `/boot`.